# Site cloned and running on .cc domain - who is the govening body of that TLD?

Tags: copyright, top-level-domains

One of our sites has been cloned and is now running as a Chinese day care centers site running on a `.cc` domain. It's extremely irritating as we put a lot of time, effort and money into designing our site, and it's just been ripped off.

I've looked online and found that a `.cc` domain is the TLD for the Cocos Islands, but couldn't find any information on the TLD's governing body who I was planning to contact in regards to this copyright infringement.

The other thing is that they haven't even changed the Google Analytics tracking code so they are now skewing our data, I've posted a [separate question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53865/3rd-party-site-using-our-google-analytic-tracking-code-skewing-our-data-how-ca) as this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The register for [.cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cc) domains is [eNIC](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-names/cc/index.xhtml?loc=en_US), which is a subsidiary of Verisign.

According to [Verisign's Digital Millennium Copyright Act](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/legal/dmca/index.xhtml) (DMCA) policy:

> Verisign respects the intellectual property rights of others and expects others to do the same. It is Verisign’s policy to respond to notices of alleged infringement that comply with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA") and other applicable intellectual property laws. Responses may include disabling a user’s ability to transmit and/or store material claimed to be the subject of infringing activity and/or terminating such user’s ability to use the application at all. If we take such measures, we will make a good-faith attempt to contact the user who stored and/or transmitted the content so that he or she may make a counter notification pursuant to sections 512(g)(2) and (3) of the DMCA. It is our policy to document all notices of alleged infringement on which we act.

Following the steps outlined [here](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/legal/dmca/index.xhtml), you can send a   complaint to: `DMCA@verisign.com` with the words "DMCA Complaint" in the subject line.

Answer (score 3):

Send a mail to the host and tell them that they are copying your content and you will take legal action against them. Most of them will immediately take action as for hosts, there is nothing to gain and everything to lose.

You can also contact the registrar but the bigger the company, the less they will care about this as they don't make money through this.